# Is there a way to get (know) all objects created from a class in the same class?

Tags: java

If I create a class `A` with some properties for example `a, b, c` and I create objects `A x1; A x2; A x3; ... A xN`. Is there a way I can create a method in the same class that retrieves all objets that I create? I want to create something like `static ArrayList <A>` to add them but I think I cannot be done it in the same class.

Comment: Yes you can, but I would ask you why do you need this? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to compare the objects that I create, so I can retrieve objects with a particular value on their property(a b c).

Comment: Then store the objects that **you** create in a collection. No need to store **all** the created As in a list inside A.

Comment: @Pulse9 then create a bunch of objects and store them in some appropriate data structure you can then search. Much simpler than trying to magically keep track of every instance of some class ever created.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private static List<A> createdAs = new ArrayList<>();

    public A() {
        synchronized(createdAs) {
            createdAs.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

But, as Luiggi says, this is probably a very bad idea, and there's probably a much cleaner way to solve your problem. One big problem this causes, for example, is that it causes a memory leak: none of the created As can be garbage-collected, even if nobody uses them anymore, since they're all referenced by the static list.

Comment: You can WeakReference your way out of the leak, not that it makes this any less terrible an idea.

Comment: @pvg still not a good idea. You're trying to fix a bad solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure what gave you that idea given it's the opposite of what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by simply recording that you created them:

```
class A {
    private static List<A> instances = new ArrayList<A>();

    public A() {
        instances.add(this)
    }

    public static List<A> getInstances() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(instances);
    }
}
```